# Visual Studio Code shows a lot of errors in Cypress

Tags: testing, visual-studio-code, cypress

I have a question with VSCode. I developed tests with Cypress and VS didn't show any problem. In fact, this tests are working right now. However, VS Code shows a lot of stranges errors today. For example 'describe' is not defined. (no-undef)' or 'Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8. (indent)' as you can see in the image.

I did not change the VS Code Settings. Why is it happening?

**UPDATE**: I think the problem is the new version of Cypress 7.5, but i have not found a solution yet

[image: Erros in VS Code in Cypress Tests]

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Answer (score 1):

I have also hit this issue and I suspect it was because I interrupted the installation,

You can try the below and overcome the issues, Its working fine for me now.

npx cypress install --force or
yarn cypress install --force (depending on the package manager in use),

Make sure that the installation of Cypress is complete,

After install please verify the cypress installation npx cypress verify.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix that with this steps:

File / Preferences / Settings then Text Editor (or just search for 'tab' in the search settings box)

Then remove the tick from the following settings:

Insert Spaces
Detect Indentation

But it didnt' work. FInally, I had to remove the JS6 VS Extensions and this errors dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

That was My problem too, The exact error was:

> Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6. eslint([indent](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent))

And to fix that, I just let ESLint knows that "I don't want it to take care of those indentations".

There're two approaches for that (base on the [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules)):

#### 1. Using configuration comment

Put the following comment at the very top of each file you want that indentation to be ignored:

```js
/* eslint-disable indent */
```

#### 2. Using configuration file

To disable the indentation rule for a group of files (ex. test.js or spec.js), use the following code snippet in the `.eslintrc` file:

```js
{
  /* Whatever's here */,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*-test.js","*.spec.js"],
      "rules": {
        "indent": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```